# bash hex 14digits incremental (yes, it's a bruteforce)

Tags: android, bash, shell, hex, fastboot

I am trying to make a bash cript to bruteforce attack an android oem bootloader key to unlock the fastboot.
I made this script

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
setopt c_bases
typeset -i 16 num
for num in $( seq $((0x10000000000000)) 1 $((0xffffffffffffff)) ); do 
    echo "$num"
    fastboot oem unlock $num
done
```

but i have problems because iif i try to execute it i run out of ram. Is there any way to make an incremental script like this without running out of memory?
Thanks a lot

Comment: On my 24 core Haswell system, I can fork ~20k programs per second. If `fastboot` doesn't need any time to talk to the device and is perfectly parallelizable, this would take me 100,000 years. Good luck!

Comment: Well, i dn't have so much spare tine, so i will have to ask for the unlocking code... Thanks antway!

Answer (score 2):

```
for num in $( seq $((0x10000000000000)) 1 $((0xffffffffffffff)) ); do
```

will never work, because the entire command substitution output will be placed in memory before the loop is invoked. Use a c-style loop (bash specific) for loops with many iterations:

```
for ((num=0x10000000000000;num<=0xffffffffffffff;num++)); do
```

You may also consider using gnu parallel to improve the speed of the test.